# Script creation of Builds and Releases in TFS 2015

Tags: continuous-integration, tfs-2015, continuous-deployment, vnext

I recently finished figuring out a Build and Release process for our environment using TFS 2015 vNext build and release tasks.  I'll now need to duplicate that several dozen projects.  I've been looking around and I see no way to automate or script this process.  Is it possible to script the creation of builds and releases or create them from a pre-populated template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not any official solution and task could do this for now. There has been a feature request in **user voice** and with STARTED  status, you can vote up and monitor it

> **VSO build vnext: share build templates between projects**
>   https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8468566-vso-build-vnext-share-build-templates-between-pro

As a workaround, you could use an [Export/Import Build Definition extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.ExportImportBuildDefinition) in Visual Studio Marketplace. However, it's only work with build definition.For release definition, give a try with this one [Clone release definition (for TFS 2015 U2 and above)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.rm-import-export).